# Avoiding redundancy when using both a SimpleSchema and a ValidatedMethod for a meteor collection?

Tags: validation, meteor, simple-schema, meteor-methods

In a meteor web app, is having both a SimpleSchema and a ValidatedMethod redundant? When trying to reuse the previously defined schema I get a syntax error.

Here is what I mean:
                                                                             `mycollection.js`

```
export const myCollection = new Mongo.Collection('myCollection');

export const mySchema = new SimpleSchema({
   a_field:String;
});

myCollection.attachSchema(mySchema);
```

Now for the insert method:
`methods.js`

```
import {mySchema, myCollection} from mycollection.js;

export const insertMethod = new ValidatedMethod({
    name:'insertMethod',
    validate:new SimpleSchema({ 
        mySchema,           /*Shows a syntax error: How to avoid repeating the schema?*/
    }).validator(),
    run(args){
        myCollection.insert(args);
    }
});
```

For this simple example, it would be "ok" to rewrite `a_field:String` to the validated method's Schema. For more complicated examples however this seems pretty redundant, and what about if I want to use some of the previously defined schema and add some new fields for validation without having to copy the whole thing over?

Comment: Simple schema when tied to a collection takes care of validations both at the client as well as from the server. Since client side validations are generally untrusted, the validations again take place at the server side (Which is deemed trusted). You could look at [simple schema validators](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#validation-options) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as you before, this is what I did:

```
import { ValidatedMethod } from 'meteor/mdg:validated-method';
import { Reviews } from '../../Reviews/Reviews.js';

export const insertReview = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'insertReview',
  validate: Reviews.simpleSchema().validator(),
  run(data) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

If you need exclude some fields:

```
import { ValidatedMethod } from 'meteor/mdg:validated-method';
import { Reviews } from '../../Reviews/Reviews.js';

const newReviewsSchema = Reviews.simpleSchema().omit([
  'field1',
  'field2',
]);

export const insertReview = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'insertReview',
  validate: newReviewsSchema.validator(),
  run(data) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

And when you need to extend the schema:

```
import { ValidatedMethod } from 'meteor/mdg:validated-method';
import { Reviews } from '../../Reviews/Reviews.js';

export const insertReview = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'insertReview',
  validate: new SimpleSchema([
    Reviews.simpleSchema(),
    new SimpleSchema({
      newField: {
        type: String,
      }
    }),
  ]).validator(),
  run(data) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, this is what I ended up using although it follows quite naturally from the above answer (difference is that I use the Schema itself rather than retrieving it from the collection):

```
import {mySchema, myCollection} from mycollection.js;

export const insertMethod = new ValidatedMethod({
    name:'insertMethod',
    validate:new SimpleSchema([ 
        mySchema,          
    ]).validator(),
    run(args){
        myCollection.insert(args);
    }
});
```